# How to Gather incoming objects in a List Globally per Thread

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am sending an object of data to a controller that has to store each object in a list of objects each time the controller gets called until all objects are gathered and ready for processing.

I am not very good with terminology but i think this is called buffering.

I have this:

```
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
        private readonly List<int> _objectList;
        public MyController()
        {
            if (_objectList == null)
            {
                _objectList = new List<int>();
            }
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public void Index(int newObject)
        {
            _objectList.Add(newObject);
            Console.Write($"object {newObject} added");
        }
    }
```

So every time post data to the controller _objectList always starts null. How can i keep saving all data that goes into Index as long as the application is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controllers are created and recycled for each request so that's why `_objectList` always starts null.

If you want to save all data that goes into Index as long as the application is running you could use ASP.NET Application State which is accessed through the `Application` property on the `HttpContext` object. This object will be available across all sessions. If you want a separate `_objectList` per session you would use Session State which is accessed through the `Session` property on the `HttpContext` object.

Answer (score 0):

I would initialize MyController with dependency injection. This keeps the controller responsibility to handling the incoming data but not worry about how the data is stored. Something along the lines of this..

```
public class MyController
{
   private IStoreInts storage;    
   public MyController(IStoreInts storage){this.storage = storage;}

    [HttpPost]
    public void Index(int value){
      storage.Add(value);
     }
}
```